# What is the best way to call inline function in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump, ipopt

I think the key challenge in my code is calling these in line functions:

```
rr(τ) = 1/((1+prstp)^(tstep*(τ-1)))
```

I am calling it in the following way:

```
@NLconstraint(dice_model,
              UTILITY == sum((C[i]^(1-elasmu)*l[i]/(1-elasmu)) * rr(1.0) for i in 1:100))
```

[image: error coming when I call this]

Comment: Do you get any errors or unexpected results? The image shows just a warning, which wouldn't affect further processing. It also says what step you can take to avoid the warning too: register the function with the model, as shown in the message. Can you update the question with where you're having problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: register the function like the warning helpfully tells you to
- Option 2: replace `rr(1.0)` by a constant. In an earlier line have `my_const = rr(1.0)`, and then in the nonlinear expression use `my_const` instead of `rr(1.0)`.